How send data to MassTransit consumer using .NET Core 7 console
I have two projects in my solution, one is console and other one is API. In the API project, I set up MassTransit as follows:
using MassTransit;
using Notification;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<NotificationRequestConsumer>();
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("notificationQueue", ep =>
        {
            ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
            ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));
            ep.ConfigureConsumer<NotificationRequestConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

And the NotificationRequestConsumer as follows:
public class NotificationRequestConsumer : IConsumer<INotificationRequest>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<INotificationRequest> context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(context.Message.Event);

       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Now I need to send message to this consumer, how can I do this?
I set up the Program.cs as follows:
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, config) =>
                {
                    config.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
}

But I'm stuck at sending the message to that consumer. Please help me solve this issue.

First make sure the message contract (INotificationRequest) is defined in a shared library accessible by both the console application and the API project.In your console application, you'll need to publish a message instance that conforms to the INotificationRequest contract. here is the sample code:
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        var publishEndpoint = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IPublishEndpoint>();

        var message = new NotificationRequest
        {
            Event = "Sample Event"
        };

        await publishEndpoint.Publish<INotificationRequest>(message);

        Console.WriteLine("Message published");
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, config) =>
                    {
                        config.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
                        {
                            h.Username("guest");
                            h.Password("guest");
                        });
                    });
                    x.AddPublishMessageScheduler();
                });
            });
}

